# How to add message back to Rabbit MQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

The subscriber (handler scripts) receives messages from Rabbit MQ queue.

Then it checks message, do some operations. How to add handled message to back to queue if condition is not right? Is it possible in Rabbit MQ?

Comment: can you specify your scenario?  As i know Rabbit MQ has `Topics`, `Publish/Subscribers` ,  why not just use it when it meets your topics or subscribe when you need the message?

Comment: For example there is mesage in queue:  obj = {'date': '2017'} Handler subscribes to channel and get this message. Then checks if date == 2017, if not it adds message back to queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `autoAcknowledge` to `false` and once you're "done with the message"- just reject it, that is [send negative acknowledgement](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html). Once it sees that the message has been nACKed, rabbitmq will re-queue it.

Comment: The caveat here being that there is nothing to prevent the same consumer from getting the message again.

Comment: Is there a way to delay to re-consumption of this message by the same consumer?